# 3 x 3 char vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am starting learning C++ I try to declare a 3x3 vector and I did the following:

`std::vector<std::vector<char>> matrix(3, std::vector<int>(3));`

Thats give me an error, althoug it works fine when the type is int:

`std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(3, std::vector<int>(3));`

I would be very grateful if someone come explain what I am doing wrong and how to declare a 3x3 vector in C++. I know how to do that with a matrix.

I have google but I have not been able to find the solution. I woul be very grateful If someone recommends a good book or an online course to learn C ++ for someone new to the subject.

Thank you in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: You have a typo in the type of vector - `std::vector<std::vector<char>> matrix(3, std::vector<int>(3);` should be `std::vector<std::vector<char>> matrix(3, std::vector<char>(3));`

Comment: To make the comment by @Yksisarvinen a little bit clearer, you have a vector of `std::vector<char>`, but then you initialize it using `std::vector<int>(3)`.

Comment: *Thats give me an error...* Although it's not hard to see what the problem is in this case, in general if you're asking about code that produces an error, tell us what error you're seeing. It's best to paste in the exact text of the error.

Comment: Please don't accept answers that solve the wrong problem. *Or* don't update your question in response to answers (or solutions in comments). That makes the answers and comments, as well as your whole question, kind of useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me there is no any difference between 'char' matrix and between 'int' matrix.

The thing is that you forgot a parenthesis at the end of line. It should be:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(3, std::vector<int>(3));
```

or

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> matrix(3, std::vector<char>(3));
```

The point is that you should use a compilator to detect more easily this errors.
For example in Visual Studio I get:

> error C2059: syntax error : ';'

Comment: That's not the only error, and is more likely a typo in writing the question (as indicated by the edit)

Comment: @Lambert Duran, thanks, that solves my problem. I thought that, std::vector<int>(3), will be the second dimension of the vector. Have too many to learn.